# Compiler warning when setting up SceneDelegate for @EnvironmentObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, environmentobject

I'm trying to implement @EnvironmentObject to pass an array from a View in one tab to another view in another tab.

I get the yellow compiler warning:

> Initialization of immutable value 'reportView' was never used;
> consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

in SceneDelegate.swift

Here is my SceneDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var questionsAsked = QuestionsAsked()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        ProductsStore.shared.initializeProducts()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
          let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
          window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MotherView().environmentObject(ViewRouter()))
          self.window = window
          window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        let reportView = ReportView().environmentObject(questionsAsked)
    }
}
```

Here is my ObservabelObject:

```
import Foundation

class QuestionsAsked: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sectionThings = [SectionThing]()
    @Published var memoryPalaceThings = [MemoryPalaceThing]()
}
```

I use:

```
@EnvironmentObject var questionsAsked: QuestionsAsked
```

in my view that generates the data to be passed around.

I pass in the data like so:

```
questionsAsked.sectionThings = testSectionThings ?? []
```

In the view where the data is to be passed to I have:

```
@EnvironmentObject var questionsAsked: QuestionsAsked
```

I then access it as follows:

```
totalThings += questionsAsked.sectionThings.count
totalThings += questionsAsked.memoryPalaceThings.count
```

Comment: You are not using reportView in any way. Thats what the "warning" is all about. In your case its probably best to just delete it.

Comment: and where is that tab view?

Comment: @burnsi How do I inject the environment object into a view then? FYI let reportView = ReportView().environmentObject(questionsAsked) should be let homeView = HomeView().environmentObject(questionsAsked). That is equivalent to the ContentView that appears in every new project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the line in question is useless as it will not be presented in the Scene. The only view that is presented is `MotherView`. In order to pass `questionsAsked` down to that view you just append it like the other `.environmentObject`. So this should read:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    // this really need to be @StateObject´s
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    @StateObject var questionsAsked = QuestionsAsked()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        ProductsStore.shared.initializeProducts()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
          let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            //Inject them here into the MotherView
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MotherView().environmentObject(viewRouter).environmentObject(questionsAsked))
          self.window = window
          window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

In the `MotherView` and descending Views you can now access them by the `@EnvironmentObject` wrapper.